# Data binding not working but works fine in tutorial

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js

I am new to `knockout.js`. I am following [this](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=loadingsaving) tutorial. It is working fine on knockout site but not for me. Error console is also not showing any error.
Below is my code
View:

#### Tasks

```
<form data-bind="submit: addTask">
    Add task: <input data-bind="value: newTaskText" placeholder="What needs to be done?" />
    <button type="submit">Add</button>
</form>
<div >
<ul data-bind="foreach: tasks, visible: tasks().length > 0" id="testing">
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isDone" />
        <input data-bind="value: title, disable: isDone" />
        <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.removeTask">Delete</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

View Model:

```
<script>
function Task(data) {
    this.title = ko.observable(data.title);
    this.isDone = ko.observable(data.isDone);
}

function TaskListViewModel() {
    // Data
    var self = this;
    self.tasks = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.newTaskText = ko.observable();
    self.incompleteTasks = ko.computed(function() {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.tasks(), function(task) { return !task.isDone() });
    });

    // Operations
    self.addTask = function() {
        self.tasks.push(new Task({ title: this.newTaskText() }));
        self.newTaskText("");
    };
    self.removeTask = function(task) { self.tasks.remove(task) };
}

ko.applyBindings(new TaskListViewModel(),document.getElementById("testing"));
</script>
```

Comment: If you want serious feedback on your issue you'll have to provide more details - have you included the knockout library? how about your stylesheet? have you tried stepping through the code?

Comment: @mhoff all files are correctly included as I can see it via firebug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the ko.applyBindings doesn't apply to all data-bind attributes. Move your "testing" id to a place where it covers all the HTML code with the relevant "data-bind" attributes.

Comment: ah it should also work with this.newTaskText() because it's a closure. Do you see any warnings in your browser console?

Comment: yes. all are related to css issues except this one `Use of Mutation Events is Depreciated. Use MutationObserver Instead`

Comment: the ko.applyBindings call doesn't include the binding inside the form. Maybe you should make a div with the id "testing" around your html code.